# How to vectorize a function not 'inside' but 'outside' in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to program [tic-tac-toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) in R - here are my two functions for making a move and evaluating all valid moves (the ones are X's, zeros are O's and `NA` is not taken yet):

```
move <- function(board,square,mark)
{
  if (square < 1 || square > 9 || !is.na(board[square]))
  {
    return(NA)
  }
  else
    board[square] <- mark
    return(board)
}

valid.moves <- function(board)
{
  return(which(is.na(board)))
}
```

Now setting up a test position, evaluating all valid moves and then make those moves...

```
test.last <- matrix(c(1,1,NA,0,NA,0,NA,0,1),nrow=3)
moves <- valid.moves(test.last)
move(test.last,moves,1)
```

...gives a result which I didn't intend:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1
```

I wanted to have *three different boards with the respective valid moves* (which will then be evaluated with another function whether it is a winning position) and *not one board with all valid moves made at once*.

I don't want to do this with a loop but the vectorization should not take place all at once 'inside' the `move` function but 'outside' of it - so basically I want to do the following without a loop (the `eval.pos` function to evaluate the position is of the form `eval.pos <- function(board){}`):

```
for (i in 1:length(moves))
{
  after.moves <- move(test.last,moves[i],1)
  print(after.moves)
  print(eval.pos(after.moves))
}
```

How can I accomplish this without a loop?

Comment: Although, this is just a `mapply`, see -perhaps- something like `Vectorize(move, "square", SIMPLIFY = F)(test.last, moves, 1)`

Comment: `which` returns a length-3 vector in this case. You might have had better luck using the arr.ind=TRUE option so you could identify the matrix indices.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat: I tried that but I find this solution a little bit easier because you only have one number as coordinates.

Comment: If one of the answers "works" for you then you need to checkmark it. Otherwise people will assume there remains an outstanding unsolved issue.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat: Thank you, I am well aware how the system works ;-)

Comment: OK. I only commented because it seemed from your comments that Neil Fulz' answer had succeeded. I guess not?

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat: Well, I am afraid not 100% because I am still a little bit bothered about the extra complexity of the resulting list, that you don't normally need when you use vectorization. But perhaps there is no other way...

Comment: If my method is not delivering what you wanted, then you need to edit your question to clarify. Unless you are calling that one too complicated as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
move2 <- function(board, square, mark) {
  lapply(square, function(x,i,value) `[<-`(x,i,value), x=board, value=mark) 
}
```

Note that the anonymous `function()` is needed because `[<-` is primitive.

Comment: +1: Great thank you. How can I use the output of the function directly as input for my `eval.pos` function which is of the form `eval.pos <- function(board){}`? With `eval.pos(move2(test.last,moves,1))` I get the following error: `Error in board[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: `lapply` returns a list; I suppose you could use it again for `eval.pos` also, eg `lapply(X, eval.pos)` with `X` being the result of `move2`

Comment: Ok, that works too. What is a little bit bulky is that one now has all these lists as containers. Do you think that there could be a solution that does the same trick without lists as with standard vectorization (which also doesn't use lists as containers)?

Comment: @vonjd like `sapply`?

Comment: @rawr: To be honest with you the whole 'apply' family of functions still confuses me! I just want to get a vector back of all the evaluated board positions after the respective valid moves habe been made: `eval.pos(move2(test.last,moves,1))`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my suggestion in the comment. How to use matrix indices to generate a list of move options:

```
 valid.moves <- function(board)
 {
     return(which(is.na(board), arr.ind=TRUE))
 }

> moves <- valid.moves(test.last)
> moves
     row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   2   2
[3,]   1   3

> lapply(1:3, function( mv) {start <- test.last 
                             start[matrix(moves[mv,],ncol=2)] <- 1
                             start})
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0   NA
[2,]    1   NA    0
[3,]    1    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0   NA
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]   NA    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    1   NA    0
[3,]   NA    0    1
```

Comment: +1: Thank you! What I find a little bit bulky also with this solution is that one now has a list as a container. Do you think that there could be a solution that does the same trick without a list as is the case with standard vectorization (which also doesn't use lists as containers)?  I just want to get a vector back of all the evaluated board positions after the respective valid moves have been made: `eval.pos(move2(test.last,moves,1))`

Comment: A list is the only structure that can deliver three separate matrices in a useful package. If you used `sapply` you would have gotten a 9 x 3 matrix which would not have seemed as natural for doing the evaluation that I'm guessing you would want to do. Or are you just creating random moves?